# Java Firebase-Admin missing GoogleCredentials

Tags: java, firebase, authentication, credentials, firebase-admin

I want to make a Server Application that has Access to my Firebase Database.

I followed this Guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk

But I get the following error:

> cannot resolve GoogleCredentials

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new 
   FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
   .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
   .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
   .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

EDIT:

After importing the following Libraries:

> - org.json.jar
> - netty-all-4.0.0.final.jar
> - google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar
> - google-http-client-1.16.0-rc-sources.jar
> - firebase-admin-5.9.0.jar
> - google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.9.0.jar
> - google-auth-library-credentials-0.9.0.jar
> - google-api-client-1.23.0.jar
> - google-api-client-1.4.1-beta.jar
> - guava-24.0-jre.jar
> - google-http-client-jackson2-1.23.0.jar
> - jackson-core-2.9.4.jar
> - slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
> - slf4j-jdk14-1.7.25.jar
> - api-common-1.3.9.jar

Im stuck at this Error:

> Feb 27, 2018 2:15:33 PM com.google.firebase.database.logging.LogWrapper error
>   SCHWERWIEGEND: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (5.9.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(ILjava/util/concurrent/Executor;)V
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.NettyWebSocketClient.(NettyWebSocketClient.java:71)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$DefaultWSClientFactory.newClient(WebsocketConnection.java:435)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.(WebsocketConnection.java:80)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.(WebsocketConnection.java:68)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection$DefaultWebsocketConnectionFactory.newConnection(Connection.java:297)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.(Connection.java:72)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.(Connection.java:57)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$DefaultConnectionFactory.newConnection(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1303)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.openNetworkConnection(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:547)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.access$800(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:37)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$1$1.onSuccess(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:500)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context$1$1.onSuccess(Context.java:67)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.core.JvmAuthTokenProvider.getToken(JvmAuthTokenProvider.java:66)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context$1.getToken(Context.java:62)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$1.run(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:490)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.util.RetryHelper$1.run(RetryHelper.java:93)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Please provide the exact error that you are getting. Paste it here.

Comment: Make sure you have the right import: `import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;`

Comment: what role would u add to the service account to : FirebaseApp.initializeApp and FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUserByEmail, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUser , i wanna avoid add the firebase admin to the SA, since it is too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Netty 4.1.x. I would recommend taking a dependency on `4.1.17.Final` which is what the Admin SDK depends on. Your dependency management tool (Maven, Gradle etc.) should handle this for you.

Comment: Thanks, changing netty-all-4.0.0.final.jar to netty-all-4.1.17.final.jar solved the last error and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Download this JAR and include it as external lib

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all/4.0.0.Final